# jquery.Load works only within asp.net

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

I'm quite new to jQuery and can't find out what doesn't work.

Tn the following sample the code works fine when the page is part of a asp web application.

But when I create a normal Website in IIS the load doesn't work. The event raises (tried it with alert) but nothing is loaded.

I alays asumed that jScript ( jQuery ) is independent form host mechanisms. Am i wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#MyButton').click(function () {
                //Load HTML from HelpDetails.html
                $('#OutputDiv').load('../HelpDetails.html #SubTOC');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="MyButton">Click to Get HTML</button>
    <div id="OutputDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **1.** What do you see in the console? **2.** was jQuery loaded correctly?

Comment: jQuery works on the DOM, so the server side technology used is moot. Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Is the AJAX request being made?  What response does the server give?  You need to do at least _some_ debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is **firebug console** saying ? The only reason i could think is a wrong (remote) file path. Make sure you have a file called `HelpDetails.html` in the location where jQuery load method is looking for. A **404** error ?

[image]

Comment: I guess because it's more comment role than an answer.

Comment: Thx indeed the script was not found thanks for the hint with firebug.

Comment: BTW The load only works whenthe site is hosted (e.g. IIS) right ? When just double clicking the file localy the jquery load das not work, does it?

Comment: load will work as long as you have a valid file location as the parameter. No matter it is in IIS or your local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Possible problems can be: jQuery is not loaded (but very unlikely if it works in some cases), html is not loaded. To exclude both: check the console in your browser. If you don't know why, please post which browser you are using. Also, it might be a better idea to link your jQuery to a library of another host (e.g. Google's)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Server.MapPath("~/your-path-to-jquery") to get the path to your script, might be that it just cant be found.

Comment: Sever.MapPath won't really help outside of ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Change the script line to this:

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with his script tag.  If the JavaScript resource isn't found, that's an error to be fixed.  But we don't know that.

Comment: I disagree.  If the file isn't there, it won't work.   Using the CDN would probably eliminate that issue.